# Remove numbering and edit intendation in Lyx

Tags: spacing, numbering, lyx

I need to print some python code in lyx. I have to print code like:

```
b)def sq(t, x):
      y = x**2
      return t(y)
```

But, when I try the code, in Lyx, I can't remove the inner numbering and control the spacing and indentation.

[image: as shown in the figure]

How can I remove it?

Comment: Have you tried Insert > Program Listing?

Comment: No. But, thank you. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inserting code in LyX, use Insert > Program Listing. For more information, see Help > Embedded Objects.